# Como posso mudar a cor da seleção e ponteiro do EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext

Eu quero mudar a cor da `seleção` do texto em um `EditText` e também mudar a cor da `bolinha` (o nome é ponteiro se eu não estiver enganado) pelo java.

Tem que ser igual a imagem que se segue só que com outra cor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julgo que isso não é possível alterar, de forma dinâmica(depois do EditText ter sido criado), via java.

Via XML, crie um style:

```
<style name="SelectionColor">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

aplique-o ao EditText usando

```
android:theme="@style/SelectionColor"
```

Notas:

- O exemplo usa a cor verde.
- A cor do cursor também será alterada.

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue alterar estas coisas no arquivo  values/colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#C5CAE9</color>
    <color name="accent">#00BCD4</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

Mais informações:
https://developer.android.com/samples/DirectShare/res/values/colors.html

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Você pode criar style:

```
<style name="green">
        <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="button_light">@color/button_light</item>
</style>
```

E setar no código:

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.green);
```

Mais informações:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: Tem como fazer pelo java ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com esta resposta.

Comment: Acho que essa seria a melhor resposta se houvesse mais detalhes